# Add a doctype to HTML via HTML Agility pack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I know it is easy to add elements and attributes to HTML documents with the HTML agility pack. But how can I add a doctype (e.g. the HTML5 one) to an *HtmlDocument* with the html agility pack? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Html Agility Pack parser treats the doctype as a comment node.
In order to add a doctype to an HTML document simply add a 
comment node with the desired doctype to the beginning of the document:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.Load("withoutdoctype.html");

HtmlCommentNode hcn = htmlDoc.CreateComment("<!DOCTYPE html>");

HtmlNode htmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html");
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InsertBefore(hcn, htmlNode);

htmlDoc.Save("withdoctype.html");
```

Please note, that my code does not check for the existing of a doctype.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know AgilityPack doesn't have a *direct* method to set the doctype, but as Hans mentioned, HAP treats the doctype as a comment node. So you could try to find the existing doctype first, if not create a new one and paste a desired value there:

```
var doctype = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/comment()[starts-with(.,'<!DOCTYPE')]");
if (doctype == null)
    doctype = doc.DocumentNode.PrependChild(doc.CreateComment());

doctype.InnerHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
```

Comment: Since `DOCTYPE` can be written with any mix of upper and lower, case, perhaps `/comment()[starts-with(lower-case(.),'<!DOCTYPE')]` (XPath 2) or `/comment()[starts-with(translate(., 'doctype', 'DOCTYPE'),'<!DOCTYPE')]` (XPath 1, translating D, O, C, etc. to d, o, c, etc.).