# HTML Agility Pack stripping self-closing tags from input

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html-agility-pack

This is how I'm creating my checkbox:

```
HtmlInputCheckBox checkbox = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
checkbox.ID = _Data.ControlID;
checkbox.Attributes.Add("class", "checkbox");
checkbox.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
sReplacementString = element.RenderToString();
```

`RenderToString` is an extension that does this:

```
public static string RenderToString(this Control control)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer))
        {
            control.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This produces a string with a closing tag on the input, I can see this when debugging.

```
<input name="ttWBF_1" type="checkbox" id="ttWBF_1" autocomplete="off" class="checkbox" />
```

It's then added to the HTML using the Agility Pack as such:

```
HtmlNode temp = doc.CreateElement("temp");
temp.InnerHtml = sReplacementString;
HtmlNode current = inputNode;

foreach (HtmlNode child in temp.ChildNodes)
{
    inputNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(child, current);
    current = child;
}
inputNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(inputNode);
```

However in the HTML the input tag for the checkbox is missing its self-closing slash and therefore fails WC3 validation.

```
<input name="ttWBF_1" type="checkbox" id="ttWBF_1" autocomplete="off" class="checkbox">
```

This happens with my textboxes which are generated in the same way. it looks like they're getting lost when adding the HTML to the page using the agility pack.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Which W3C validation fails? Are you expecting XHTML-output? Does HTML support self-closing tags?

Comment: Our requirements are for validation to XHTML 1.1 - we get this error: `end tag for "input" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified - You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">". `

Comment: Are you using WriteTo(TextWriter) or WriteTo(XmlWriter)? Have you set doc.OptionOutputAsXml?

Comment: Setting `doc.OptionOutputAsXml` still gives me non-closed input tags. I'm not using `WriteTo(TextWriter)` or `WriteTo(XmlWriter)`.

Comment: Why aren't you using `WriteTo(XmlWriter)`? The OptionOutput-properties determine what the `WriteTo` methods do, how are you retrieving your html? Properties like `OuterHtml` returns _html_ which is not valid xhtml.

Comment: I'm not using `WriteTo(XmlWriter)` because I'm writing a pipeline. This manipulates the HTML and then passes it back. It gets rendered elsewhere later on. Not my decision I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end it pains me to say that I fell back on processing the HTML with regex to add in the mising self-closing tag. I'd love a better solution as this is hacky and not future proof - it has to be added in for every tag that needs correcting:

```
sXHTML = Regex.Replace(sXHTML, "<input(.*?)>", "<input $1 />");
```

Answer (score 17):

Try setting "OptionWriteEmptyNodes" flag:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;

// ....
```

**UPDATE**

Since my original answer was rejected, here's another possible solution.

Are you passing the correct DOCTYPE to your HTML document before rendering it? Take a look at this SO question for how to insert a DOCTYPE: [Add a doctype to HTML via HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957525/add-a-doctype-to-html-via-html-agility-pack)

Comment: Yes, the doctype is correct. We're not adding it via the Agility Pack. The Agility Pack is only used to manipulate part of the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true; works for me too. img tags are now closed with /> instead of just >

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer - I've had the exact same issue and it'w working as expected now. The chosen answer is just a hack. Not sure why it didn't work for the op. Is there a way we can mark an answer as "community chosen" so we can surface it, instead of having it sit at the bottom of the list?

Answer (score 2):

Include this when you create your document node and it should solve your issue:

```
if (HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("input"))
{   HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["input"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;}
else
{   HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("input", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);}
```

Original answer:
[Image tag not closing with HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759355/image-tag-not-closing-with-htmlagilitypack/12096383#12096383)

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to ignore the node from agiliy pack?
For example, this line will tell to html agility pack to ignore changing this nodes.

```
  HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("meta");
```