# Problems with doctype using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xhtml, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to create a XHTMl file from scratch using HtmlAgilityPack. Following the advice presented in [Add a doctype to HTML via HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957525/add-a-doctype-to-html-via-html-agility-pack), I try to add a doctype to it:

```
private static HtmlDocument createEmptyDoc()
{
    HtmlDocument titlePage = new HtmlDocument();

    titlePage.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
    titlePage.OptionCheckSyntax = true;

    titlePage.AddDoctype();

    var html = titlePage.CreateElement("html");
    titlePage.DocumentNode.AppendChild(html);

    return titlePage;
}

public static class HtmlDocumentExtensions
{
    public static void AddDoctype(this HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        var doctype = doc.DocumentNode.PrependChild(doc.CreateComment("<!doctype html  PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd\">"));
    }
}
```

However, when I write this document to a file, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!--type html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.d-->
<html />
```

The doctype really gets treated as a comment and some characters are replaced by dashes. How can I solve this and write the doctype as-is to the file?

EDIT: Added custom extension to HtmlDocument

Comment: I'm not on Windows, so I cannot test this, but it seems you're not following the advice in those answers. Also, it's possible that  `OptionOutputAsXml = true` could be causing part of the problem.

Comment: check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Comment: @w0lf can you tell me where I'm not following the advice? I need `OptionOutputAsXml = true` because I want a XHTML document.

Comment: @Thaoden My hunch is that `OptionOutputAsXml` produces the `<?xml version="1.0" ...` tag that you definitely don't need. The samples in the link seemed a bit different.

Comment: @w0lf have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#strict, the xml declaration is "strongly recommended". My original problem was with the doctype, not the xml decl.

Comment: @Thaoden My bad! It's good to know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = @"
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A!!</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>2!!</td>
        <td>te43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> !!</td>
        <td>.!!</td>
        <td>te53</td>
        <td>te2</td>
        <td>texx</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h4 class=""nikstyle_title""><a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""http://www.niksalehi.com/ccount/click.php?ref=ZDNkM0xuQmxjbk5wWVc1MkxtTnZiUT09&id=117""><span class=""text-matn-title-bold-black"">my text</span></a></h4>

</body>
</html>";

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            var doctype = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/comment()[starts-with(.,'<!DOCTYPE')]");
            if (doctype == null)
                doctype = doc.DocumentNode.PrependChild(doc.CreateComment());

            doctype.InnerHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html>";

            string html2 = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

        }
```

The code in other question gives you the way to do it. Here is full example.

Comment: This works, although I don't see the difference to my code. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            HtmlNode docNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
            HtmlNode rootNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
            doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(rootNode);
            doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(docNode);
            doc.Save("test.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One pedantic remark: the doctype declaration is not actually a "root node" (that would be the `html` element). In SGML parlance, it would be a "markup declaration".